# Query with more than one like condition, with order by LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, plsql

I am using the more than one like, and try to get the order by main keyword "sun screen", but I'm not getting the result as I want, please check my query.

```
select productName from products
where product like "%sun%"
   or product like "%screen%" 
   or product like "%sun screen%"
order by product like "sun screen %"
```

Result should be:

```
sun screen olyiv
sun screen dabaga
sun bla
screen bla bla
```

Please help to get the result.

Comment: That last `like` at the very end seems to be wrong.

Comment: With SQL you can use "IN" operator to achieve the "OR" as `SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City IN ('Paris','London');`

Comment: Thanks @kurenai kunai , IN does't work with my scenario DB is huge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `ORDER BY CASE`:

```
SELECT p.productName 
FROM products p
WHERE p.productName LIKE '%sun%' 
   OR p.productName LIKE '%screen%'
   OR p.productName LIKE '%sun screen%' 
ORDER BY CASE
   WHEN p.productName LIKE '%sun screen%' THEN 1
   ELSE 2
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
Select productName from products 
where productName like "%sun%" 
or productName like "%screen%" 
or productName like "%sun screen%" 
Order by CASE WHEN (productName like "sun screen %") THEN NULL
              ELSE productName END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP`as below

```
WHERE product REGEXP 'sun|sun screen'
```

[See more](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-regexps.htm)